# Tuning of Cloudify Java parameters

Tags: cloudify

I am using Cloudify 2.7 with OpenStack Icehouse.

I would like know if it exists a documentation about the tuning of Cloudify JVM parameters.

For example, how should I configure correctly the gs.properties file into the /config directory?

Does it exist other files I should configure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cloudify JVM parameters are configured using the cloud driver configuration file. There are advanced settings to tweak both memory and port settings. These are available here:
http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/bootstrapping/advanced_cloud_driver_usage.html

For instance:

```
rest {
                 //Rest port
                 port 8102
                 minMemory "128m"
                 maxMemory "64m"
}
```